# Using private member variable as private function parameter

Tags: c++, oop

```
class C
{
public:
  void clearWithParam()
  {
    clearImage(image, size);
  }
  void clearWithoutParam()
  {
    clearImage();
  }
private:
  unsigned char* image;
  size_t size;

  void clearImage(unsigned char* image, size_t& size)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
      image[i] = 0;
    }
  }

  void clearImage()
  {
    for(int i=0; i<this->size; i++)
    {
      this->image[i] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I found there are two ways of implementing private methods. Two `clearImage()`s here do exactly the same thing. However the first one takes private members `image` and `size` as its parameters, and the second access the private member directly. Which one is more preferred?

Comment: It's up to you. The first one is more useful. If I planned to "clear" more than one buffer, I would use that. The second version should call the first. But really the first function shouldn't be a member function at all, as it doesn't operate on the class. At least it should be static. Normally, I'd hide it altogether by implementing it in the source file under an anonymous namespace.

Comment: Note that in either case, you have a type mismatch using `int` in your loop with a `size_t` size. Also note that there are simpler ways to zero memory, using `std::memset` or `std::fill`.

Comment: They aren't the same. The first takes 2 parameters that accidentally have the same name as private members, but can be called with any arguments of the right type. It does not operate on any private members unless the caller happens to specify that.

Comment: The first one does does not take private members as its parameters (the arguments have the same name as members, but that doesn't automatically link the two) unless you specifically wrote code that calls it and passes those members.    For example, the version with no arguments could be implemented as a call of `clearImage(this->image, this->size)`.  As to which style is preferred it depends on needs of your program - but, in your example as shown, there's little practical difference between `someC.clearImage(anotherC.image, anotherC.size)` and `anotherC.clearImage()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the rules that govern scope, the function args are given preference over the members of the same name.  Since the instance remains accessible, you can still access the member variables via things like `this->image`.

Some people prefer to try and avoid such ambiguity and have established a fairly popular (to the point of it being adopted into c++ code quality requirements in some places) naming convention of having all members begin with a `m_` prefix.  Great time savings compared to typing `this->` and reading it too.  When code is clear yet more fits on a screen at once, it tends to reduce scrolling required for review too.

Furthermore, if a function needs nothing from the instance, consider adding the static modifier.